# I am getting status 404 while running Spring MVC app on server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

My files are as shown below. I am not able to figure out. The error is:
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Type Status Report

Message /onlineshoppingrks/

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.1
This is my web.xml file
Web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>


    <!-- Configuring front controller -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

<!--  it should go through the front controller -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is my PageController file
PageController

```
package net.rks.onlineshoppingrks.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class PageController {

    @RequestMapping(value= {"/","/home","/index"})
    public ModelAndView index() {

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("page");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

This is my dispatcher-servlet file
dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
    <beans xmlns="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd      
   ">

    <context:component-scan base-package="net.rks.onlineshoppingrks.controller"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />

    </bean>

</beans>
```

I am trying to build a onlineshopping web app.

Comment: Which url you want to load on browser ?

Comment: This is the url i have been trying.. http://localhost:8080/onlineshoppingrks/

Comment: can you please share the project directory structure

Comment: I do not know what was the problem but after updating Maven it started to work fine. Thanks though.